# Strange memory leak on Mac (Chrome, Firefox and Safari) with our GWT based web UI

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gwt, memory-leaks, profiler

We are experiencing a serious memory problem in our GWT based web application when running in Mac, for Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

For example, with Firefox, when looking at the Activity Monitor on Mac, the memory consumption is quickly increasing across time, even through frequent refreshes, and can reach 1 GB after a significant session. Similar phenomena happens for Chrome and Safari.

But, we cannot see a real reason using various profiling tools, including Java JProfiler (for GWT) and Chrome profiler and timeline looking at native JS, listeners and DOM elements.

Actually there are 2 related problems here:

1. The memory is increasing while using the UI for along time without refresh. In this case, we can see some uncollected garbage SVG elements (we are using SVG based canvas) that are unreachable, but the memory increase in the Activity Monitor is much higher than what we would expect with this garbage.
2. The memory remains high even after multiple refreshes, and even though the profiler shows that all the above garbage is completely gone.

We are chasing this leak for a while, with no results, so I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Yaron.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem occurs only on Mac?
2. What GWT version are you using? 2.5?
3. Did you saw this issue https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6938?

I faced several issues with leaks using GWT before, but in 2.5 version it works fine, even in IE!

Answer (score 0):

I've tracked down some leaks in my GWT application before, and it's certainly not easy to determine where they're coming from thanks to Java's garbage collector hiding what's going on.  The most common reason for a leak would be cyclical references, so multiple objects can't be garbage collected because they reference each other.  They're tough to spot on your own so I use a library called [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) - it also comes with a very convenient [Eclipse plugin](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html).  FindBugs literally finds anything you could possibly consider and has worked wonders for me.  BUT make sure to play with the settings first; cyclical reference checking is not enabled by default.

Bruno_Ferreira makes a good point, too - make sure you're up to date with your GWT version as they're always improving memory leaks.